# Apple Push Notifications With Foreign Accent Characters Not Receiving

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, encoding, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending push notifications and when the message contains foreign characters (Turkish in my case) like İ, ş, ç, ğ... The message does not arrive to devices.

Here's my code:

```
$message = 'THİS is push';
$passphrase = 'mypass';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'MyPemFile.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to Apple service. ' . PHP_EOL;

// Encode the payload as JSON
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
$payload = json_encode($body);

$result = 'Start'.PHP_EOL;
$tokenArray = array('mytoken');
foreach ($tokenArray as $item)
{
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Failed message'.PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Successful message'.PHP_EOL;
}

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I have tried encoding $message variable with utf8_encode() but the message received as "THÝS is push". And other ways like iconv() didn't work for me, some of them cropped Turkish characters, some didn't receive at all.

I also have

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in my page. I don't think the problem appears while I set the value but maybe with pack() function.

Any ideas to solve this without replacing characters with English?

Comment: `var_dump($payload)` - What are you trying to send? Spontaneous guess: the string is not UTF-8 encoded. Further guess: your source code is not UTF-8 encoded. Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: var_dump($payload) returns "bool(false)" when the message contains Turkish characters. but when don't, it returns "{"aps":{"alert":"This is push","sound":"default"}}" for instance. Isn't the string gets encoded when I use utf8_encode()? Also, shouldn't I see the broken characters with echo? It all looks fine when I write message to screen.

Comment: Read my linked article for what `utf8_encode` actually does.

Comment: I did, "Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8"; I got confused, tried utf8_decode() instead... It didn't work for sure. So, your spontaneous guess looks correct. How will I know what it is encoded with?

Comment: Read the rest of the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do was replacing the Turkish characters with following script:

```
function tr_to_utf($text) {   
    $text = trim($text);    
    $search = array('Ü','Ş','Ğ','Ç','İ','Ö','ü','ş','ğ','ç','ı','ö');  
    $replace = array('Ãœ','Å','&#286;','Ã‡','Ä°','Ã–','Ã¼','ÅŸ','ÄŸ','Ã§','Ä±','Ã¶');
    $new_text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);    
    return $new_text;  
}
```

Now it is working with no problems.

[This is the source](http://www.egonomik.com/2010/04/php-turkce-%C2%BB-utf-cevirici-script-ascii-to-utf-converter/).

Comment: Oh god, I'm sad to see my article had no impression on you whatsoever. This is ***not*** the right way to handle encodings. *facepalm*

Comment: I find this offensive, just because I chose a quicker path doesn't mean I don't care about the correct path. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @kubilay how did you able to make this work? doesn't work for me

Comment: @gilsaints88 How do you mean? Are you sure that the function works correctly? Remember that you need to cast returned string to a variable like $text = tr_to_utf($text); | Perhaps you are just using tr_to_utf($text); ?

Comment: @kubilay yes I am using like $text = tr_to_utf($text); and doesn't get pushed.. may I know if you added any header on your php? thanks

Comment: @gilsaints88 Unfortunately I don't have anything more in my code, it might be something else. Can you send notifications with English characters?

Comment: @kubilay yes I can send notifications in English characters. Would it be possible for me to see your entire php with the tr_to_utf? thanks... Mine is like this

<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
.....
function tr_to_utf($text) {
    $text = trim($text);
    $search = array("Ü","Ş","Ğ","Ç","İ","Ö","ü","ş","ğ","ç","ı","ö");
    $replace = array("Ãœ","Å","&#286;","Ã‡","Ä°","Ã–","Ã¼","ÅŸ","ÄŸ","Ã§","Ä±","Ã¶");
    $new_text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
    return $new_text;
}
....

Comment: @gilsaints88 Sorry for late response, it took me some time to find the code in the archives. It has been more than 2 years after the last time I've used it. You can find the code in my blog: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/?p=450

Comment: @kubilay thanks very much. Had a work around last week, I just converted the Turkish chars inside iOS code after being pushed.. (not the elegant way but.. well, ;) it will do for now...) thanks again! I'll try yours when I refactor again.

Answer (score 0):

The "n" parameter means, that you pack as unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order). I`m not sure how Apple CPU hardware handle the instructions and how convert them, but is different from the PC for sure. Try to switch the byte order, use "v" unsigned short (always 16 bit, little endian byte order).

Comment: Okay, I tried {$msg = chr(0).pack('v', 16).pack('H*', $item).pack('v', strlen($payload)).$payload;} is that what you meant? It receives nothing with this and I'm probably not doing what you said actually.

Comment: Try to read the function manual here http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php and experiment with different pack() format characters. If the problem is in the pack() function, then eventually you`ll come up with solution.