# Send Push Notification to Multiple Devices: APNS response is negative after a while

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send notifications for multiple devices. So I get tokens to an array, open connection, send notifications in a loop, close connection.

However, After 9-10 devices, it stops sending. I believe Apple somehow drops the connection .

Here's my code:

```
$message = 'Push';
$passphrase = 'mypass';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'MyPemFile.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to Apple service. ' . PHP_EOL;

// Encode the payload as JSON
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
$payload = json_encode($body);

$result = 'Start'.PHP_EOL;
$tokenArray = array('mytoken');
foreach ($tokenArray as $item)
{
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0).pack('n', 32).pack('H*', $item).pack('n', strlen($payload)).$payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Failed message'.PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Successful message'.PHP_EOL;
}
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I think I need to open connection once, send notifications then close. Should I be doing fwrite() with multiple tokens? I don't know how though. Any ideas or solutions are accepted.

By the way the answer is like:

```
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message  
Successful message
Failed message
Failed message
Failed message
Failed message
Failed message
...
Failed message
```

**P.S.** I had character issue with same code but it is solved in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704638/apple-push-notifications-with-foreign-accent-characters-not-receiving), this is another problem, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The first failed message likely has something wrong with it, at which point Apple will close the connection to signal to you that there was an issue.  If you're using the enhanced format, you have an opportunity to get some feedback before Apple closes the connection to see what was wrong with the notification you sent.  After this happens you must re-establish a connection to send more messages.

There are a number of reasons it might fail.  You might have sent an invalid device token, your payload might be invalid or of the wrong length, etc.

Best check out the documentation for APNS: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Comment: I don't think it's about an invalid token since I'm taking tokens only over app. I checked, too though. What I wonder is that if anything's wrong with the loop. Will it change if I close the connection and re-open for each 10 token?

Comment: Apple wants you to keep the connection open for as long as possible (annoying since they close it when there's an error).  There's something wrong with your notification which is causing apple to close the connection.  Why not try the enhanced format protocol?  Or better yet, try an existing library like APNS-PHP http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ and see what the issue is?

Comment: I think this is true, if I put my valid token as first entry in my database, it delivers, but if I move my token to 2nd or any other position with an invalid token as 1st entry, I never get the notification.

Comment: @Redth , please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647651/no-error-but-also-not-receive-notification-at-mobile-end-apple-device-using-php