# No error but also not receive notification at mobile end APPLE device using php

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am not good in english , i tried my best to explain question to you , if you don't understand then please ask me to explain.

I have a bunch of device tokens , i am fire notification to all the device tokens.This is a apple device token.

ex:

```
297257d9ae463410c992610a08cdff5655c2ab3cc4364fdffd6c9499df9e0cff
d520d52dfbb9f05938d1b1cbe6cf3b2452b2337df7c7696f927ac184c1eeec25
81ca0fc696bfce339f83738fde6bf3a5ffc5371b1b9c85e04e6a28ef490b9ce1
93e7b09753d3062ec0c0fd8ec89a920ee0918f9e484f5b6d72e7f4a3f7323x07
1438e78a3566cda13e2c65253ede2ccee217f3f321cad044c0922fd0c1b0cc33
6f3fc8506eca3465659211a8077af88c2d51a1e75528e5fe37b9c49258e0fz9e
8be640b2de8be3ed0b669a45de0301b33a5856a17eaf66488a7a2340fb173r9f
f8152ad30f66a0c80a2f21e4265d5fe462c8dc5b8be97cc49d4c7df865b63x11
```

This is my `php` code to fire a push notificaiton.

```
    foreach ($deviceTokens as $deviceToken) {
        try {
                $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                        continue;
        }
     }
```

the problem is due to some bad tokens notification is fired, but device is not receive that push notification.

In example 4th device token is bad token or expired token.
`93e7b09753d3062ec0c0fd8ec89a920ee0918f9e484f5b6d72e7f4a3f7323x07`.

so `foreach` loop fire notification for all devices , and i also print the result , it is printing the result upto last device, but devices token after 4th token not receive notification.

If i remove the 4th device token from the list then all the device receive the token, upto the last device token.

Is there any solution for this??